# Take two random tuples from a list, such that all elements are different

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

In Python3 I have a list of tuples as below

```
('A', object1)
('B', object5)
('B', object3)
('D', object2)
('E', object3)
('F', object1)
('G', object1)
```

I want to take two random elements from the tuple such that the first and second element of the first random tuple are different that the first and second element of the second random tuple. I.e., I can select from the above list `('A', object1) and ('B', object5)`, but I cannot select `('F', object1) and ('G', object1)` or `('B', object5) and ('B', object3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one optimized way that chooses one item using `random.sample` and finding the first item that satisfies your condition:

```
In [116]: def rand_choos(arr):
     ...:     (f1, f2) = random.sample(arr, 1)[0]
     ...:     second = next((i, j) for i, j in arr if i != f1 and j != f2)
     ...:     return (f1, f2), second
     ...: 

In [117]: 

In [117]: rand_choos(lst)
Out[117]: (('B', 5), ('A', 1))

In [118]: rand_choos(lst)
Out[118]: (('D', 2), ('A', 1))
```

Also note that in this case you'll always get same second item for a random first item (while still different to the first one) because the order of the original list never changes. If this is an issue you can shuffle the array at the leading of the function to get completely different items (not all the time tho because it's just random):

```
In [149]: def rand_choos(arr):
     ...:     arr = arr[:] # this creates a copy for preventing the function to change the array globally
     ...:     random.shuffle(arr)
     ...:     (f1, f2) = random.sample(arr, 1)[0]
     ...:     second = next((i, j) for i, j in arr if i != f1 and j != f2)
     ...:     return (f1, f2), second
     ...: 

In [150]: rand_choos(lst)
Out[150]: (('B', 3), ('G', 1))

In [151]: rand_choos(lst)
Out[151]: (('B', 3), ('A', 1))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to randomize the whole list (`random.sample(arr, len(arr)`) and then pick up the elements from there? My concern is that you are picking up the second element from the original list, so for any given first element, you'll always get the same second element.

Comment: @MatiasCicero Why on earth we should do that? we want two random elements and we have nothing to do with the order of the list. Also, by doing that which is like shuffling the array we don't change anything which in fact is not what OP wants.

Comment: @MatiasCicero yes that's a reasonable concern that I was about to add some explanation about, to the answer.

Comment: You can create a shuffled version of the array without mutating the original if that's your concern. My point is, consider that you get the first element `('B', object3)`, I can predict that the second element will be `('A', object1)`.. so that's not random at all for the second element.